# How do I get Bleeding-Edge Bootstrap 4?

Tags: bootstrap-4

How do I get Bootstrap 4 Bleeding Edge, I am already pulling V4-Dev, if this is Bleeding Edge then fair enough. Just need someone to confirm if I need to do anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pulling v4-dev alone won't give you the absolute bleeding edge. Dist/bootstrap.min.css was last changed a month ago, so it will not include later changes.

You'll also have to build bootstrap from source. From the documentation:

> 1. [Download and install Node](https://nodejs.org/download), which we use to manage our dependencies.
> 2. Install the Grunt command line tools, `grunt-cli`, with `npm install -g grunt-cli`.
> 3. Navigate to the root `/bootstrap` directory and run `npm install` to install our local dependencies listed in
>      [package.json](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/package.json).
> 4. Install Ruby, install Bundler with `gem install bundler`, and finally run `bundle install`. This will install all Ruby dependencies,
>      such as Jekyll and plugins.
> 5. Run `grunt` to run tests locally and compile the CSS and JavaScript into `/dist`.

For more info: http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/build-tools/